# Prove that $n!$ is not a divisor of $n^n$ for $n>2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof by induction.

$3! = 6$ is not a divisor of $3^3 = 27$

Now suppose that
$n!$ is not a divisor of $n^n$

$(n+1)n!= (n + 1)!$ is not a divisor of $(n + 1)n^n = n^{n + 1} + n^n $

I don't know how to go on. Maybe induction is not the way to prove the statement

Comment: Can $n-1$ be divisible by $n^n$?

Comment: I think you should have "$(n+1)n!= (n + 1)!$ is not a divisor of $(n + 1)^{n+1}$ ", right ?

Comment: @Physor In the last line I just multiplied the inductive hypothesis by $(n+1)$, but this lead nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p\leq n$ be prime.  Then $p|n!$ so if $n!|n^n$ then $p|n^n\implies p|n.$  Since $n>2$, $n-1>1$ so there is a prime $p$ that divides $n-1$.  By the above, also $p|n$ so $p|(n-(n-1))$, contradiction.

Comment: Well that is a LOT easier compared to what I did.

Comment: "Since $n>2$, $n-1>1$ so there is a prime $p$ that divides $n-1$". Why $p$ is the same that divides $n$?

Comment: @Raffaele  Suppose $n!|n^n$. *Every* prime $p < n$ then--including every prime $p$ that divides $n-1$--has to divide $n^n$ because every such $p$ divides $n!$. Which implies that every such $p$--including every prime that divides $n-1$--also divides $n$.

Comment: @Mike thank you!

Comment: @Mike maybe yesterday was not my best day. If $n!$ was a divisor of $n^n$ then it should be a divisor of $n$ but this is impossible because for $n>2$ we have $n!>n$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Raffaele no you need more than that. For example, 8 does not divide 4 and $8>4$ but 8 does divide $4^4$. You need to observe that there are primes that divide $n!$ that do not divide $n$.

Comment: ...and of course you can note that while $n! >> n$, in fact $n^n > n!$.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove there is a prime number in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which does not divide $n$.

Let $p_i$ be the $i^{th}$ prime.

Suppose the primes in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ are $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$. Suppose all of them divide $n$. Because $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ are the primes in $\{1,2,...,n\}$, $p_{m+1}>n$. But $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ divide $n$, so $n\geq p_1\cdot p_2\cdot...\cdot p_m$

So we get:

$$p_{m+1}>p_1\cdot p_2\cdot...\cdot p_m>2p_m$$

However, from Bertrand's postulate, if $p_{m+1}>2p_m$, there must be a prime between $p_{m+1}$ and $p_m$, which is a contradiction, since $p_m$ and $p_{m+1}$ are consecutive primes. (red about Bertrand's postulate [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate))

To conclude, it is impossible for all primes in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to divide $n$, so let $p$, $1\leq p\leq n$ such that $p$ does not divide $n$. Because $p$ divides $n!$, if $n!$ divided $n^n$, it means $p$ would divide $n^n$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $k^k$ is not a multiple of $k!$

Let's show $(k+1)^{k+1}$ is not a multiple of $(k+1)!$ that is equivalent to $(k+1)^k$ is not a multiple of $k!$

Since $k^k$ is not a multiple of $k!$, $k$ and some factors of $k!$ are relatively prime.

Since $k$ and $k+1$ are relatively prime, $(k+1)^k$ is not divisible by $k!$.